# SimpleCov not generating coverage for app/ code

Tags: rubygems, code-coverage

I am currently using SimpleCov to generate coverage for my Ruby code. I have it configured as follows.

```
SimpleCov.start do
  add_filter "spec/"
end
```

However, coverage reports are not generated for the app folder ( models, views, controllers etc).
The report generates coverage only for lib/ and db/

Is there something missing?